# Change content based on a drop down selection from a mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a form of drop down boxes populated with values from a mysql database (Computer Part Models). My goal is to produce the rest of the values (The part's specs) from the database below each drop down box based on the value that was selected.

Essentially what I think I think I need is some sort of div refresh for each time a new item has been selected.

I have tried different functions triggered by 'onchange' within the select tag but nothing has come up working.

Let me know if anymore code would be needed for context.

**HTML & PHP** for one drop down

```
<form id="parts">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Choose your parts</legend>
            Any parts marked with * are required<br/><br/>
            <label for="CPU">CPU*</label><br/>
            <?php
                $cresult = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pCpu ORDER BY cModel asc");
            ?>
                <select id="CPU" name="CPU">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select your Part</option>
                <?php
                while ($rows = $cresult->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $cmodel = $rows['cModel'];
                    echo "<option value='$cmodel'>$cmodel</option>";
                    $cid = $rows['ID'];
                }
                ?>
                </select>
                <br/>

                <?php
                $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT cSocket FROM pCpu WHERE ID = '$cid'");
                while($rows = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $csocket = $rows['cSocket'];
                    echo "CPU Socket: $csocket<br/>";
                }
                ?>

                <br/><br/>
```

What would be the best way of tackling this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How large is the data set?

Comment: you need to hook a function to the change event of the select.  In this function, make an ajax call and replace a 'div' content with the newly fetched data.

Comment: @Strawberry Around 100 with all tables

Comment: @CarlVerret So could this just be done with the current code but just wrapping the latter part of the code inside a div? Then with the function, would this be php as i'd need to echo the data?

Comment: from my point of view, I think you should have an empty <div> under your select and put a script tag where your javascript function would be placed. Be sure to give an id to the 'div' to be able to put the result of the ajax call in it.

Comment: @CarlVerret I've never used ajax before this and i've seen it pop up a lot while trying to get this to work. How can i go about integrating this with the content i want to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two parts in this answer :

First if you want to update a part of your page with change event on the select

```js
function myUpdateFunc()
{
  
  
  var mySelected = $("#CPU").find("option:selected").val();
  $('#divResults').html ('selected value :' + mySelected)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="parts">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Choose your parts</legend>
            Any parts marked with * are required<br/><br/>
            <label for="CPU">CPU*</label><br/>
            
                <select id="CPU" name="CPU" onchange="myUpdateFunc()">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select your Part</option>
                <option value="1">value 1</option>
                <option value="2">value 2</option>
                </select>
                <br/>

               <div id="divResults"/>

                <br/><br/>
```

Next :

If you want to query a database you can check many tutorials on this. I can help you with this as well

Comment: That's perfect so far thank you so much. From here with the query, i'm assuming i'll have to query from the js rather than how i have it so far with the php.

Comment: Sorry to add another point onto this, is it possible to simply include some PHP within the function to query the database or do I **have** to set up a new connection within js

Comment: not really a php guy... but I guess you'll have to make a call to a php endpoint on your server that is going to return the data ( a php get with the value selected as param)

Comment: I was hoping i could get away with something like this `$('#divResults').html ('<?php echo ""; ?>')` (but with a query inside the php tags).

Comment: don't think so !

Comment: No worries then, I will look into connected with js. Would this have to be through node? I'm using cpanel to host so will have to figure this from here.