# Updating div content based on a selection from a drop down menu by querying a database from a javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

I had a question answered earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58994885/change-content-based-on-a-drop-down-selection-from-a-mysql-database) that was a massive help that involved changing content using ajax based on a dropdown selection from a mysql database.

I now need to fill the contents of the editted div with the values from the same row as the selected option from the drop down menu.

In order to do this it seems that the only way is to query from my js file, and the only ways to do this is through either nodejs or further ajax. I have attempted both ways but nodejs is proving tough as I am using cpanel to host the site. Ajax would be a great way to do this but I need the query to include **WHERE** cModel = '$cModel' in order to retrieve the correct values and obviously I can't get that variable when im getting the php script from a separate file.

I apologise if i've left out some important details, this has been doing my head in massively and i wanted to see if there was any easier way to do this. Thanks!

**HTML & PHP** for one dropdown box:

```
<form id="parts">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Choose your parts</legend>
            Any parts marked with * are required<br/><br/>
            <label for="CPU">CPU*</label><br/>
            <?php
                $cresult = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pCpu ORDER BY cModel asc");
            ?>
                <select id="CPU" name="CPU" onchange="myUpdateFunc()">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select your Part</option>
                <?php
                while ($rows = $cresult->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $cmodel = $rows['cModel'];
                    echo "<option value='$cmodel'>$cmodel</option>";

                }

                ?>
                </select>

                <br/>

                <div id="divResults">

                </div>
                <br/><br/>
```

**JS**:

```
function myUpdateFunc()
{
    var mySelected = $("#CPU").find("option:selected").val();

    $('#divResults').html ('CPU Model: ' + mySelected + '<br/> CPU Socket: ')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is definitely the way to go. Call a PHP script and pass it `cModel`.

```js
function myUpdateFunc()
{
  var mySelected = $("#CPU").find("option:selected").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "searchCPU.php?cmodel=" + mySelected, 
    success: function(result){
    $('#divResults').html ('CPU Model: ' + result + '<br/> CPU Socket: ')
     }
  });
}
```

**searchCPU.php**

```php
<?php
    $cmodelParam = $_GET['cmodel'];
    $cresult = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pCpu WHERE cModel = $cmodelParam");
    //assuming it returns a single row for simplicity
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cresult);
    echo $row['cModel'];
?>
```

Obviously you can do more error checking and this is open to [SQL injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You should always use [prepared statements](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-prepared-statements.php). I didn't alter it to simply answer your question and let you resolve those issues on your own.

Comment: Thank you so much! Been trying to figure this out for ages now. You've saved me a lot of further heart ache. Definitely need to look further into how php, JS and ajax can all integrate, still very new.

Comment: The basics are any website is just HTML and javascript and CSS. It can all be in one .html file. You can make any beautiful webpage and save it as a HTML file on your computer and a web browser will pull it up. PHP just "scripts" the HTML before it gets sent out thus making your webpage dynamic. Any server-side language for websites works this way.

Comment: Yeah i’ve been working with standard html + css for a while now, i’m just a novice with php and certain aspects of js. Thanks again for the assistance!